# MVC: Code cached for individual view. Cases exception that shouldn't exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, view

We have a project that's being worked on by 4 developers. Sometimes an exception that shouldn't exists pops up and  people starts to scratch their heads why it happend. Usually it says "Could not load type '' from assembly ''.

The type it's trying to load no longer exist so making a reference to it would without a doubt cause this exception. Problem is that no code refers to this type anymore even though the view says it does.
Last time this happen it was a this piece of code which threw the exception

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout.cshtml";
    MyProfile profile = MyProfile.GetUserProfile();    
}
```

It said:

```
Could not load type 'MyProject.Lib.MyService.Services.MyProfileBase' from assembly 'MyProject.Lib.MyService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

If i check history in our source control on the "MyProfile" class I can see that it inherited from the class "MyProfileBase" yesterday but has since been removed.

So why would it still try to load this old code?
The fix for this is simple. All I need to do is edit the Index.cshtml view with anything. It can be just a newline or a space somewhere. Then the exception goes away.
Question is, why this happens? Does anyone recognize it? It's almost like the code is being cached for this indiviual view.

Before we realized that all we needed to do was edit the view, we could spend wasted time troubleshooting this. Recycling the application pool or even doing an IISreset would not help with this exception.

Comment: ASP.NET caches views in the system temp folders. To avoid this happening in deployment you can pre-compile views on publish.

Comment: If you're talking about the Temporary ASP.NET Files then I've tried that. When I got the error and tried to delete all temp-files I would still get the same error

Comment: Well that is the only place views are cached.